# Oracle Archive and Purge Options

Tags: oracle, performance, bulk-operations

I am trying to figure out what are the best options to perform archive and purge given our situation.

We have roughly **50 million records** in say Table A. We want to **archive data into a target table** and then **purge those data in the source table**. We would like to retain the data base on several criteria that overlap with each other. For example, we want to retain the data from the past 5 months in addition to keeping all the records with say Indicator='True'. Indicator='True' will likely return records beyond 5 months. This means I have to use **OR** condition in order to capture the data. Base on the conditions, we would need to **retain 10 million records** and **archive/purge 40 million records**. I would need to create a process that will run every 6 months to do this.

My question is, what are the **most efficient options** for me to get this done for both archiving and purging? Would a **PROC/bulk delete/insert** be my best option?

**Partition** seems to be out of the question since there are several conditions that overlap with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [composite partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-8F38C8B0-3999-4F4E-8AF2-F41C2F764F47.htm), e.g. *range* (for your time dimension) and *list* (to distinct between the rows that should be kept long and limited time.

**Example**

The rows with `KEEP_ID='N'`  should be eliminated after 5 months.

```
CREATE TABLE tab
  ( id            NUMBER(38,0),
    trans_dt      DATE,
    keep_id       VARCHAR2(1)
  )
 PARTITION BY RANGE (trans_dt) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))
 SUBPARTITION BY LIST (keep_id)
   SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
   ( SUBPARTITION p_catalog VALUES ('Y'),
     SUBPARTITION p_internet VALUES ('N')
   )
 (PARTITION p_init VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019','dd-MON-yyyy'))
  );
```

Populate  with sample data for 6 months

```
insert into tab (id, trans_dt, keep_id)
select rownum, add_months(date'2019-08-01', trunc((rownum-1) / 2)), decode(mod(rownum,2),0,'Y','N') 
from dual connect by level <= 12;

select * from tab
order by trans_dt, keep_id; 

        ID TRANS_DT            KEEP_ID
---------- ------------------- -------
         1 01.08.2019 00:00:00 N       --- this subpartition should be deleted
         2 01.08.2019 00:00:00 Y       
         3 01.09.2019 00:00:00 N       
         4 01.09.2019 00:00:00 Y       
         5 01.10.2019 00:00:00 N       
         6 01.10.2019 00:00:00 Y       
         7 01.11.2019 00:00:00 N       
         8 01.11.2019 00:00:00 Y       
         9 01.12.2019 00:00:00 N       
        10 01.12.2019 00:00:00 Y       
        11 01.01.2020 00:00:00 N       
        12 01.01.2020 00:00:00 Y
```

Now use [partition extended names](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51150) to reference the subpartition that should be dropped.

Drop subpartition older than 5 months, but only for KEEP_ID = 'N'

```
 alter table tab drop subpartition for (DATE'2019-08-01','N');
```

New data

```
        ID TRANS_DT            KEEP_ID
---------- ------------------- -------
         2 01.08.2019 00:00:00 Y       
         3 01.09.2019 00:00:00 N       
         4 01.09.2019 00:00:00 Y   
.....
```